# Replacing substring in a string using python

Tags: python

I have an query string in Python as follows:

```
query = "select name from company where id = 13 order by name;"
```

I want to be able to change the `id` dynamically. Thus I want to find `id = 13` and replace it with a new id.

I can do it as follows:

```
query.replace("id = 13", "id = {}".format(some_new_id))
```

But if in the query is `id= 13` or `id=13` or `id =13`, `...` it will not work.

How to avoid that?

Comment: How about using prepared statements?

Comment: It would probably be better to just not have the query as one string from the start. That's just going to complicate things.

Comment: If you are passing your query to some kind of function to execute it, the function should accept additional parameters, so it would be `execute('select name from company where id = %s order by name', params=(some_new_id,))`

Comment: To everyone that posted an answer based on string formatting (or re?sub etc): please learn to use prepared statements when working on SQL queries - unless you don't mind opening your code to SQL injections of course.

Comment: Check your DB adapter's documentation for parameter substitution.

Comment: Read this quick primer to avoid SQL injection in python: http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Answer (score 1):

Gluing variables directly into your query leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

If you are passing your query to a function to be executed in your database, that function should accept additional parameters.

For instance,

```
query = "select name from company where id = %s order by name"
cursor.execute(query, params=(some_other_id,))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use formatted sql.

**Ex:**

```
query = "select name from company where id = %s order by name;".
cursor.execute(query, (id,))
```

Comment: Then why do you just answer "use `str.format`" instead of posting the correct solution (and explaining why) ?

Comment: This is not what I want. I get `"select name from company where id = 13 order by name;"` as it is, I cannot add `{}` or something else inside

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution when it comes to dynamically building strings is string formatting, ie

```
tpl = "Hello {name}, how are you"
for name in ("little", "bobby", "table"):
    print(tpl.format(name))
```

**BUT** (and that's a BIG "but"): you do **NOT** want to do this for SQL queries (assuming you want to pass this query to your db using your db's python api).

There are two reasons to not use string formatting here: the first one is that correctly handling quoting and escaping is tricky at best, the second and much more important one is that [it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injections attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

So in this case, the proper solution is to [use prepared statements instead](http://bobby-tables.com/python):

```
# assuming MySQL which uses "%" as placeholder, 
# consult your db-api module's documentation for 
# the proper placeholder

sql = "select name from company where id=%s order by name"
cursor = yourdbconnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, [your_id_here])
```